# How to connect to Azure AD SAML to my existing .net webforms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, single-sign-on

I am new to Azure AD Samil, my organization wants to use SSO from Azure SAML with our existing web forms application.

I have all the info Entity ID, App name, IDP Login URL, IDP Logout URL, App Federation Metadata Url, Certificate

Now, what should I do to my code and server to start using the SSO?

Comment: That depends a lot on your specific situation. Is your existing app already using AD logings? Are you planning on migrating all of your login responsibility to AAD for all applications you are planning to have SSO for?

Comment: Hi @Hiyasat, Please reply to above comment if you are still looking for help?